# Return a yes, no value from another sheet using If Index Match formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a master sheet which pulls data from another workbook.

the workbook is called example.xlsx. This workbook has multiple sheets inside of it.

In this Master sheet I have created the formula below;

```
=IF(INDEX('[example.xlsx]sheet1'!F:F>0,"Yes","No"),MATCH(B8,'[example.xlsx]sheet1'!A:A,0))
```

I get a #VALUE error.

B8 = master sheet = name of a person
F:F = example.xlsx = is a column of numbers ranging from 0 - 9+
A:A = example.xlsx = a list of names.

=================================

original formula before i used IF

```
=INDEX('[example.xlsx]sheet1'!F:F,MATCH(B8,'[example.xlsx]sheet1'!A:A,0))
```

- this will bring back a value of 29

=================================

Can anyone point me in the right direction please so that instead of 29, it will show a Yes or No based on t is greater than a number(5)?

Comment: You are not using INDEX correctly

Comment: Thanks for that. I know I am using it incorrectly, I am asking for some help and assistance on where I am going wrong and how I could rectify it?

Comment: *In this Master sheet I have created the formula below* You build it using formula builder or input it manually? Try to build it step-by-step using additional columns, and, when success, compile everything back into one complex formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below, let me know if this works for you:

```
=IF(INDEX([example.xlsx]sheet1!F:F,MATCH(B8,[example.xlsx]sheet1!A:A,0),1)>0,"yes","no")
```

This will return a `Yes` in place of any number returned from your original `INDEX` formula that is greater than 0

Comment: Thanks Peter! much appreciated, I tried this myself, to only realise that i didn't have the ,1 before the >0. What does that do exactly?

Comment: That is part of the INDEX, and specifies which COLUMN to look in, since your array sheet1!F:F you only need to look in the first column, the MATCH part specifies which ROW to look in